# How to count number of flashes using opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to count number of flashes using opencv. The setup is; I have a video camera staring at a blinking flashlight, and using opencv functions I am trying to detect the number of flashes in the video stream coming from the camera. what is the easiest way of doing so? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a video camera (!) you would capture a video stream and then in each frame check for a bright region.

Start here http://docs.opencv.org/ and get a [video capture working](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture)

How to detect the flash depends on how much of the image it covers - if it completely fills the frame it might be as simple as find the average pixel value of the image

Comment: This won't be all that accurate if the flash rate is too fast or if flashes are not synchronized with the frame rate.